# Set color to ListView Android with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

My app is a simple list, where the main screen has a `listview` of several items fetched from the database via `simplecursoradapter`. I have tried so many links, but am not getting the desired result. I have mentioned about all answers and why they are not working for me after all the codes below.

---

**Codes**

Here is the `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/topic"
    android:textColor="#ff2e7d13"
    android:textColorHighlight="#fff4de10"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/newList"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topic"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoiceModal"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    ></ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And below is `tasks.xml` file which manages individual list items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/task_row"
android:background="@drawable/selector"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/c1"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textColor="#ff663ccc"
    android:textStyle="bold"
   />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/c2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/c1"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ff4a9fcc"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to programmatically change the colour of individual list items based on some conditions. For example, I have an extra column that can take 3 values: Low, High, Normal - I want items with High to be red, Low to be green and so on.

The following is `MainActivity.java` file:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DbHelper db;
ListView myList;
RelativeLayout rL;
int checkedCount;
int totalCount;
long arr[];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new DbHelper(this);
    arr = new long[1000];

checkedCount=0; totalCount = 0;
myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newList);

loadData();
    myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    myList.setItemsCanFocus(true);
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {
        Bundle passdata = new Bundle();
        Cursor listCursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        int nameId = listCursor.getInt(listCursor
                .getColumnIndex(db._ID));
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
         //String  a = Integer.toString(nameId);
        passdata.putInt("keyid", nameId);
        Intent passIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                EditActivity.class);
        passIntent.putExtras(passdata);
        startActivity(passIntent);
    }
});
    myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        // Called when the user long-clicks on someView
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
          /*  if (mActionMode != null) {

                return false;

            }
*/
            // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback defined above
            //    mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionMode.Callback);

            view.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }
     @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            return false;
        }
    });
    myList.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                              long id, boolean checked) {
            // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected,
            // such as update the title in the CAB
         //   Log.d("no.: "+myList.getCheckedItemPosition()+" hi","list");
rL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.task_row);

            if(checked)
            {
                //db.delData(id);

                checkedCount++; totalCount++;
                arr[checkedCount]=id;

          //      Log.d(" yo "," pos=" + position);
            }

            else {
                for(int i=1;i<=checkedCount;i++)
                {
                    if(arr[i]==id)
                        arr[i]=0;
                }
                  // checkedCount--;
                totalCount--;
                    }
            mode.setTitle(totalCount+" selected");

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_delete:
                    //   deleteSelectedItems();
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                    // Setting Dialog Title
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Delete");

                    // Setting Dialog Message
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Delete "+checkedCount+" items?");

                    // Setting Icon to Dialog
                    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.abc_list_selector_holo_dark);

                    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("DELETE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                            // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully deleted "+checkedCount+" items.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            for (int i = 1; i <= checkedCount; ++i) {
                                db.delData(arr[i]);
                                //  Log.d("TAG", arr[i] + " got here");
                                loadData();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled Delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    // Showing Alert Message
                    alertDialog.show();

                        mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB

                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu for the CAB
            menu.clear();
            checkedCount=0; totalCount=0;
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_main, menu);
            return true;
        }


        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
            // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.
            loadData();
        }


        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
            // an invalidate() request
            return false;
        }
    });
}


@Override

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    loadData();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.menu_add) {
        addNew();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void loadData()
{
    Cursor cursor = null;
        cursor = db.fetchData();
    final int[] colors = new int[] { 0xAA5F82A6 , 0xAA1A4C80 };

    ListAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.tasks,
            cursor,
            new String[]{db.COLUMN_1, db.COLUMN_2},
            new int[]{R.id.c1, R.id.c2}, 0){

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c1);
           //text.setBackgroundColor(0xAA1A4C80);
            int colorPos = position % colors.length;
            try {
                text.setTextColor(colors[colorPos]);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return view;
        }
    };
   myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}
public void addNew()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}



}
```

---

**Things I tried**

1. As you can see from the code, I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931121/android-how-to-change-the-background-colors-of-listitems-in-a-listview-managed). It does not give me any error, but colors only the first item. If I remove the `try-catch` block, it gives `NullPointerException`.
2. If I use the `Binder` way, from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5573609/4427938) (1<sup>st</sup> code) or this [link](http://iswwwup.com/t/7b626dfb7111/java-using-simplecursoradapter-viewbinder-to-change-the-color-of-view.html), I get two errors - expected `;` after the last `}`, and Cannot resolve method `SetViewBinder(...)`.
3. Most of the answers from other links suggest using a custom adapter, but I have to use `SimpleCursorAdapter` only because other parts of the code are structured that way (using cursors for fetching data from sqlite database etc.).

---

**Note**

I am a beginner, so please guide me on how to *correctly* color the items. More specifically, I want something like this:

```
 if(db.Column_Priority=="High")
     listItem.setColor("Red");
 else if(db.Column_Priority=="Low")
     listItem.setColor("Green");
 else
     listItem.setColor("Blue");
```

Is there no simple way to achieve this other than defining extra classes?

Answer (score 1):

well, in tasks.xml you have your custom view for each item in listView, so you can programatically change RelativeLayout color 
Yes, you need to use SimpleCursorAdapter, a class like this:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemList>
{
    public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<ItemList> objects)
   {
      super(context, 0, objects);
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
   {
    ItemList currentItem = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks, parent, false);
    }

    //Instanciate text and color
    TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);

    //Asignar valores
    name.setText(currentItem.getName());
    rl.setImageResource(currentItem.getCategoria(setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(currentItem.getColor()))));

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getView(position,convertView,parent);
 }
}
```

The you need an object to your adapter (ItemList.java):

```
public class ItemList
{
  private String name;
  private int color;

  public ItemList(String nm, int c)
  {
     this.name = nm;
     this.color = c;
  }

public void setName(String n)
{   this.name = n;    }

public void setColor(int c){
    this.color=c;
}

public String getName(){return name;}
public int getColor(){return color;}
 @Override
 public String toString(){return name;}
}
```

and in activity you create:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
  ArrayAdapter adapter;
  ListView list;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_tramites);

      list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewfromlayout);
      List items = new ArrayList<ItemList>();
      // add your items
      items.add(new ItemList("item 1",Color.RED));
      items.add(new ItemList("item 2",Color.BLUE));
      items.add(new ItemList("item 3",Color.GREEN));

      //Initialize the adapter with data
      adaptador = new ItemListaTramitesAdapter(this,items);
      //linked list to adapter
      lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
      //set listener
      lista.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);
  }

  // listener
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
  {
    ItemList task = (ItemList)adapter.getItem(position);

    Toast.makeText(this, "selected: "+task.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

}
```